# how to change my project name Arabic name?

Tags: android, android-studio

how to change my project name becouse I want it to Appare on mobile under the logo  when its run the problem is I want to chane the name in to an Arabic name on android studio ?? it will not accapet 
error massge invald pakage name :(

thank you

Comment: Package names have to be valid Java package names. Your app name shown to the user is usually a string resource, usually named `app_name`, and is not the package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a folder in the res/ folder with values-ar/ folder and create a string.xml in the value-ar/ folder and have the arabic names in this strings.xml file

You can refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: That's great! I'm glad I could help. Can you please accept this as an answer